# WSO2ESB JMS Proxy Consuming from Apache Kafka

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb

I have been using WSO2ESB with ActiveMQ for some time.  However, I wish to try switching this out for Apache Kafka.

I have managed to get the ESB to produce to a Kafka topic but I cannot figure out how to get the JMS proxy to consume from this queue.  I'm fairly certain it comes down to the settings in the \repository\conf\axis2\axis2.xml file:

```
       <parameter name="someFactory" locked="false">
            <parameter name="java.naming.factory.initial" locked="false">org.apache.activemq.jndi.ActiveMQInitialContextFactory</parameter>
            <parameter name="java.naming.provider.url" locked="false">tcp://localhost:61610</parameter>
            <parameter name="transport.jms.ConnectionFactoryJNDIName" locked="false">QueueConnectionFactory</parameter>
            <parameter name="transport.jms.ConnectionFactoryType" locked="false">queue</parameter>
        </parameter>
```

These settings were taken from the WSO2 sample on ActiveMQs.  I cannot find any documentation relating to using the WSO2ESB with Kafka, so I wondered if this was even possible?  If so, how can I change the above settings to get them to communicate?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

WSO2 ESB 4.8.* or less does not support for kafka but it will be supported by the ESB 4.9.0 as it is still in the development stage and Kafka support will be implemented as an inbound endpoint ( for listener ) and ESB connector ( for sender ). These are new ESB constructs which are available in ESB 4.9.0.

Comment: Okay, thanks for the information.  Is there any estimation on when 4.9 will be available?

Answer (score 1):

WSo2 ESB 4.9 will be released on end of Q1 2015.

Answer (score 0):

Kafka inbound endpoint had been released with ESB 4.9.0 for consuming data from the queue. In the blog, Kafka Support with ESB 4.9.0 has been explained with [use cases](http://rkathees.blogspot.com/2015/09/wso2-esb-490-kafka-support.html) and how to tune [performance](http://rkathees.blogspot.com/2016/04/wso2-esb-kafka-inbound-and-kafka.html) of Kafka inbound endpoint using inbound thread pool.